# How to cross reference lstnewenvironments?

Tags: listings

I have made a `lstnewenvironment` in my document. I am unable to cross reference it.

Here's the code

```
\lstnewenvironment{customlistings}[3]{
\lstset{
numbers=left,
language=#3,
breaklines=true ,
keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries ,
numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray} ,
commentstyle=\color{green!30!black},
stringstyle = \color{violet},
morekeywords={\begin, \label, \documentclass
, \usepackage, \caption},
label=#2
}
\refstepcounter{counterA}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large{Listing \thecounterA: #1}} \\
\textbf{\normalsize{#2}}
\end{center}
}{}
```

Here's how I have used it.

```
\begin{customlistings}{[LaTeX]TeX}{The listings package}{TeX}
\begin{lstlisting}
%Your code goes here

%This is usually how you present code in \LaTex, without worrying about accidentally  ..         

\end{lstlisting}

\label{trickq}
\end{customlistings}
```

I want to reference it and it should appear as "Listing 1" with 1 being the reference,
I tried a lot of things which include looking up on google, trying to put this code in another environment and then using \label but then my label continues from previous label i.e it shows 4.2 in the document instead of 1.
Please help

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `listing` package instead of doing things manually.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,listing}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstnewenvironment{customlisting}[2][]
 {\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    numbers=left,
    language=#2,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    commentstyle=\color{green!30!black},
    stringstyle = \color{violet},
    morekeywords={\begin, \label, \documentclass, \usepackage, \caption},
    #1,
  }%
 }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}

\begin{customlisting}{[LaTeX]TeX}
%Your code goes here

%This is usually how you present code in \LaTex, without worrying about accidentally  ..
\end{customlisting}

\caption{The listing package}\label{TeX}

\end{listing}

\ref{TeX} is a listing

\end{document}
```

You can customize the appearance of the caption with the `caption` package.

[image]